# What is really Grapevine Communication?

Tags: american-english

What is **grapevine communication**?  I don't know whether it has positive or negative connotations. Can anyone tell me the details of it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about learning English as outlined in our help center: [Help Center > Asking](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: if my question is irrelevant then I'll remove my post. sorry

Comment: I can't find an option in mobile apps to remove my Question if you help me to find that option.

Comment: I think that this is a reasonable question if you remove the "useful" bit, which I have done. @user97750, I hope that the question still matches what you want to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're referring to the idiom ['through the grapevine'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grapevine) which means

> Through or via an informal means of communication or information, especially gossip

Whether it is *useful* or not depends on the culture of your workplace/surroundings, and not something we at ELL can answer.

['Heard it through the grapevine'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7dGdrP3pms) is a well-known pop song.

Comment: Well-known pop song it may be, but I would hesitate to recommend it on a site for English language learners! "I heard it through the grapevine / Not much longer would you be mine" : this is [Yoda-speak](http://theweek.com/articles/442256/why-strangely-yoda-speaks), not English.

Comment: @TonyK - I wouldn't call it Yoda-speak, I'd call it rephrasing to fit the meter and rhyming scheme of the song. (Any resemblance to Yoda-speak at the end of such wordsmithing would be coincidental.)

Comment: Now that _useful_ has been edited to _positive or negative_, I think we can answer that: it's situationally dependent.  If we are talking about backbiting and gossip, then "grapevine" communication can be destructive. However, not all of it needs to be. "I heard through the grapevine that they might reopen the café across the street" is likely just fine.

Comment: @J.R.: I was trying to be polite. To this day I can't understand how professional song-writers (Whitfield and Strong) could come up with such a clunky line. It ruins the song for me.